# SQLite CASE WHEN with >= evaluation

Tags: sqlite, case-when

I am writing a script that will calculate a score for a board game called Agricola. The following query works:

```
SELECT
CASE $Fields WHEN 0 THEN -1
             WHEN 1 THEN -1
             WHEN 2 THEN 1
             WHEN 3 THEN 2
             WHEN 4 THEN 3             
END
;
```

The following query will NOT work:

```
SELECT
CASE $Fields WHEN 0 THEN -1
             WHEN 1 THEN -1
             WHEN 2 THEN 1
             WHEN 3 THEN 2
             WHEN 4 THEN 3
             WHEN >= 5 THEN 4
END
;
```

All that I get is a message essentially saying "error near '>=': syntax error". How can I represent this WHEN >= 5 block inside of this CASE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the alternative form of the `CASE` expression, you may use inequalities:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN $Fields = 0 THEN -1
         WHEN $Fields = 1 THEN -1
         WHEN $Fields = 2 THEN 1
         WHEN $Fields = 3 THEN 2
         WHEN $Fields = 4 THEN 3
         WHEN $Fields >= 5 THEN 4
    END;
```

If you want to keep using your form of `CASE`, one option here would be to bucket the `$Fields >= 5` case into the `ELSE` condition.  This would assume that `$Fields` would never be negative.  Assuming this, you could try:

```
SELECT
    CASE $Fields WHEN 0 THEN -1
                 WHEN 1 THEN -1
                 WHEN 2 THEN 1
                 WHEN 3 THEN 2
                 WHEN 4 THEN 3
                 ELSE 4
    END;
```

Comment: This was very helpful - the value would never be negative, so this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE x` will only evaluate on single values, you need `CASE WHEN x ...`, like so:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN $Fields >= 5 THEN 4
         WHEN $Fields = 4 THEN 3
         -- so on
       END
```